# Como eu altero o valor de uma variável PHP através do clique de um link?

Tags: php

Por exemplo, tenho uma variável chamada:

```
$idEmpreendimento = "1";
```

Gostaria que, ao clicar em um determinado link, eu pudesse alterar este valor para 2. É possível?

--------------------------- EDIT ~ Solução

Para quem quiser a solução, consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Alterei a variável para:

```
$idEmpreendimento = (isset($_GET["id"])) ? $_GET["id"] : "1";
```

E nos links, eu colocava, por exemplo

```
<a href="?id=1">Link</a>
```

Neste caso específico, eu acabei puxando o número do id diretamente do banco de dados com um:

```
echo "<li><a href='?id=" . $Listagem['id'] . "#imoveis" . "'>" . $Listagem['nome'] . "</a></li>";
```

Qualquer um que tiver uma dúvida semelhante e quiser perguntar, fique à vontade.

Comment: O problema é que você tem que lembrar que quando a pessoa clicou no link, o PHP já foi executado e já acabou. O que é possível é seu link chamar um PHP que mude uma variável de sessão, por exemplo, para você poder usar essa variável depois em outro PHP.

Comment: Entendi... acho que vou precisar de Ajax pra recarregar o conteúdo em questão então... porque a ideia é a seguinte:

Eu tenho uma série de empreendimentos cadastrados no banco e um determinado lugar para mostrá-los, mas apenas um de cada vez. Hoje, eu puxo da tabela apenas os dados do empreendimento com ID=1.

Quando eu clicar no segundo empreendimento, preciso que ele mude essa variável para 2 e carregue novamente os conteúdos relativos ao empreendimento 2, e assim por diante...

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Acho que você pode esquecer completamente essa coisa da variável e já montar o link certo. Por exemplo, se o usuário está vendo o empreendimento 17, o link já vai ser montado como "visualizar.php?emp=18". Assim você já mata os 2 problemas de uma vez. O link "proximo" e "anterior" já apontariam pro empreendimento correto a ser carregado no clique.

Comment: Entendi... e como funciona esse lance aí? Ainda sou meio iniciante com PHP, vou tentando fazer as coisas à medida que parece fazer sentido na minha cabeça, hehehe.

Comment: obviamente que primeiro você precisa aprender o básico da linguagem, fazendo uns testes. Entre as coisas, é bom aprender o uso do `$_GET` para pegar o `id` do link em vez de começar com uma variável, e na hora de montar a página, você vai usar algo do tipo `echo '<a href="visualizar.php?id='.(id+1).'">'` (mas estou simplificando, não tem como ensinar tudo numa pergunta do site, dê uma estudada no PHP, e nos exemplos das páginas das funções).

Comment: Entendi... beleza, valeu pela dica!

Comment: Edita a tua pergunta, retira a componente de resposta e responde à tua pergunta com a solução para o teu problema (forma correta de dares a conhecer a solução).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `$_GET` como descrito nos comentários.

Monte o link

```
<a href="link-para-pagina.php?id=2">Link</a>
```

<sub>Depois do `?` no link, é declarado as variáveis `$_GET`, se você quiser várias, use `&` para separa-las, assim: `link-para-pagina.php?id=2&grupo=7`.</sub>

E receba as variáveis:

```
$idEmpreendimento = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '1');
```

<sub>A expressão significa que se a variável `$_GET['id']` foi declarada, então a variável `$idEmpreendimento` vai receber o valor dela, senão vai receber o valor padrão `1`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma "Simples" seria,
Utilize Ajax e $_SESSION. Você cria uma sessão e cada click envia uma mensagem via ajax para uma página que atualiza o valor da sessão.

```
$_SESSION['contador'] += 1;
```

Em seguida recupere o valor da sessão também via ajax. E depois passe para PHP quando precisar.